# Terraform : Create multiple Azure Policies using for_each?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create multiple Azure Policies and I don't want to create the policies one after another. I would like to use for_each to define multiple Azure Policies. How do I do this?

For example, I have the following Azure Policies defined separately which should be created using the for_each or in any other better way like powershell https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/azure-enterprise-policy-as-code-a-new-approach/ba-p/3607843

```
// Deny creation of resource groups missing certain tags
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "require-tag-owner-on-rg" {
  name                = "require-tag-owner-on-rg"
  policy_type         = "Custom"
  mode                = "All"
  display_name        = "Require tag 'owner' on resource group"
  management_group_name = var.management-group-name

  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "category": "Custom"
    }
METADATA

  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
    {   
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
          },
          {
            "field": "tags['owner']",
            "exists": "false"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
POLICY_RULE

}

// Deny creation of resource except in EastUS
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "only-deploy-in-eastus" {
  name                = "only-deploy-in-eastus"
  policy_type         = "Custom"
  mode                = "All"
  display_name        = "only-deploy-in-eastus"
  management_group_id = data.azurerm_management_group.parent-mg.id

  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
    {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "location",
        "equals": "eastus"
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Deny"
    }
  }
POLICY_RULE
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried using*** ***"for_each"*** ***to create policies with definitions in terraform environment for your code as detailed below.***

```bash
terraform{
required_providers {
     azurerm = {
       source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
       version = "3.37.0"
     }
   }
 }
   provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
 }
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG" {
  name = "example"
  location = "EastUS"
  }
 resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "policy" {
   for_each = {
     policy1 = "Create"
     policy2 = "Use"
     policy3 = "New"
   }
   name     = each.key
   policy_type         = "Custom"
  mode                = "All"
  display_name        = each.value
  
  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "category": "Custom"
    }
METADATA
  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
    {   
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
          },
          {
            "field": "tags['xxxxx']",
            "exists": "false"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
POLICY_RULE

}
```

`terraform init`:

[image]

`terraform plan`

[image]

`terraform apply`:

[image]

***Created in portal after deployment:***

[image]